# Is it possible to prepopulate field using a before insert trigger?

Tags: apex, soql, custom-object, lookup, before-trigger

```
 trigger MyTrigger on Benifit__c (before insert) 
{
    Set<Id> lookupIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Benifit__c b : Trigger.new) 
{
    if (b.company__c != null) 
    {
        lookupIds.add(b.company__c);
    }
}

Map<Id, company__c> compRec = new Map<Id, company__c>([
        select Id, medical_location__c,date_of_subscription__c,medical_description__c
        from company__c
        where Id in :lookupIds
        ]);
for (Benifit__c b : Trigger.new) 
{
    if (b.company__c != null) 
    {
        company__c c = compRec.get(b.company__c);
        b.medical_location__c = c.medical_location__c;
        b.date_of_subscription__c = r.date_of_subscription__c;
        b.medical_description__c = r.medical_description__c; 

    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you just need to use formula fields???

Comment: Or a Process Builder, if you just want a snapshot. If you're not familiar with Apex, you can get this done using multiple types of declarative automation.

Comment: Or a Workflow Rule, since we're piling on with alternatives. :D

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: cannot be a process builder, have to be a trigger. This is what I have so far, but I don't think it is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is (mostly) fine - it's just incomplete. You correctly accumulate lookup values, perform a single, bulkified query, and then iterate over your `Trigger.new` set to perform updates.

```
for (Benifit__c : Trigger.new) {
    if (company__c != null) {
        company__c a = companyRecords.get(company__c);
    }
}
```

There's just two problems here:

1. You don't actually perform any updates. You've got three fields queried in each `Company__c`:

   - `medical_location__c`
   - `date_of_subscription__c`
   - `medical_description__c`

and you need to write assignment statements to copy these values from the `Company__c` you locate with your `Map` onto the `Benifit__c` in your `for` loop.

and

2. You have a couple of syntax errors. You refer to `company__c`, which is the identifier of an sObject class and can't be `null`, rather than the  lookup field on the `Benifit__c` object. You don't currently have a way to refer to that field,  because you do not supply a variable name (say `b`) for each `Benefit__c` record.

You need to write

```
for (Benifit__c b : Trigger.new) {
```

and

```
if (b.company__c != null) {
```

in both of your loops, and change all other references to the *field* `Company__c` in the same way.

Comment: thanks. I made edits to my code. Is there a way to have my trigger run when there is no user input? Right now, my trigger is overwriting my user inputs.

Comment: Sure, just check for `null` (if non-string field) or use the `String.isBlank()`/`String/isNotBlank()` functions to check before you populate.

Comment: i did that within my last if statement. Within I added nested if statements 
if(b.medical_location__c == null)
{b.medical_location__c = c.medical_location__c;} but the trigger still overwrites it

Answer (score 0):

You can prpopulate fields in before insert trigger but that is not recommended (why to write code when you can do it out of the box).
Because you can achieve the same with either

1. Formula field
2. Workflow rule with formula field update
3. Process Builder

Here is how you write formula

```
company__r.medical_location__c
```